# What does (char *)0 mean in C?

Tags: c, syntax

```
if ( fgets( line, sizeof(line), stdin ) == (char*) 0 )...
```

I don't understand what this line does, anyone knows?

Comment: What parts of it don't you understand?

Comment: @Martinho: Could you expand on that?

Comment: @Martinho: Yes, that's true.  Of course, it works if `line` is an actual array type.

Comment: @Oli: mistook fgets for gets :) It can only go UB if line is `char* line;` and less than sizeof(char*) was allocated for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
(char*) 0
```

Is not a null character, but a pointer to a character at address 0.

A character containing the value 0 would be:

```
(char) 0
```

Comment: It's not a pointer to a character @ address 0, it's a pointer to null character  (http://www.lysator.liu.se/c/c-faq/c-1.html)

Comment: @KevinDTimm char* c = (char*) 0 points to 0 whatever value may be there (although it doesn't matter as on most platform it would be illegal memory).

Comment: @compile-fan the type is different. The literal 0 should be on most implementation of type int (being int and n-bit integer as wide as your registers). (char*) simply casts it to a char-pointer.

Comment: What does `(char *)1` mean then?

Answer (score 4):

That's a rather odd way of writing a test for the return of a null pointer which indicates an error in `fgets()`.

I'd write it like this:

```
if (!fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin))
```

Comment: That's personal taste.  My personal taste would always to be compare with `NULL`, because that follows the semantics of the function (it's not returning a boolean).

Comment: I agree with Oli, and this opinion is also shared by the widely recognized MISRA-C standard. Only boolean expressions should be compared with boolean operators.

Comment: @Oli @Lundin My feeling is that you can't make a silk purse from a sow's ear, and that there's little point trying.

Answer (score 2):

It means a null pointer to char. It would be the same if you replace the (char*)0 with NULL. In this particular case it is checking if there is nothing more to read from the stdin. I think is just a way to be cryptic and showing some spectacular and beautiful features. If you replace it with a NULL you gain in readability without changing the semantic.

Comment: actually, it means a pointer to the null char - there is a difference

Comment: @Kevin Actually, it doesn't. fgets() returns a pointer that may be NULL. So this code is just a weirdo way of comparing the result against NULL, it has nothing to do do with the nul character.

Comment: ignoring fgets(), IMHO (char *)0 means - pointer to null char, or char pointer to null, but not null pointer to char - it seems to be just semantics, but I believe there is a difference.

Comment: It doesn't mean a pointer to the "null char", which is (char)0. In this case the pointer is zero, while to be a pointer to the null char, the pointer would have to be non-null and point to a memory address where the first byte is set to 0.

Answer (score 1):

The line checks if `fgets` return 0. The cast to `char*` is only to match the return type of `fgets`:

```
char * fgets ( char * str, int num, FILE * stream );
```

But 0 is implicit converted to `char*` if you remove it.

If you need more information on `fgets` look [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fgets/)

Answer (score 1):

(char*)0 creates the "null" pointer. So you are seeing if the value of fgets is null.

The documentation for fgets states that it returns null when there is an error or you have reached end of file.

The full statement appears to be checking if you are at the end of the file, and if so breaking out (though that's a guess).

Answer (score -2):

It is simply checking the results of fgets for null character pointer.

According to [cplusplus.com](http://cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fgets/)

> **Return Value**
>
> On success, the function
> returns the same str parameter. If the
> End-of-File is encountered and no
> characters have been read, the
> contents of str remain unchanged and a
> null pointer is returned.
>
> If an error
> occurs, a null pointer is returned.
>
> Use either ferror or feof to check
> whether an error happened or the
> End-of-File was reached.