# What does (char*) 0 mean?

Tags: c, pointers, null, char-pointer

This is a question in reference to this question:
[What does (char *)0 mean in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6072931/what-does-char-0-mean-in-c)

There the answers slightly deviated away from explaining what exactly the answer was, but the final answer mentioned that it was *a pointer to a character at address 0* and that it was null. This brought up two doubts for me:

1. In C, can I have `char* 9` and say that it is a pointer to address 9? Won't I get an error or a warning?
2. Let's say that `(char*) 0` is indeed *a pointer to character at address 0*, what does this address 0 mean? I mean how can we say it's a null? In that case what would the value of `(char*) 1`, `(char*) 2`, etc. be?

---

Context: I initially searched for an answer to this question when I figured the last argument in the user-space wrapper `execl`
would be null but instead I saw a rather odd looking syntax for it, i.e., `(char *) 0`.

Comment: You can  define `char *p = (char *)9;` (without warnings), but you can not dereference it, take a look to http://c-faq.com/null/

Comment: It's important to know that a null-pointer doesn't actually have to be a pointer to address `0`, a null-pointer is actually system dependent. *However*, the integer zero when casted to a pointer (any pointer really) is converted by the compiler to the system-dependent null-pointer.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`(char *) 0` is not a "pointer to a character at address 0". In C `(char *) 0` is treated in a special way - it is guaranteed to produce a *null-pointer value* of type `char *`. Formally it does not point to any `char` object. Its actual numerical value (the "address") is implementation-defined and can correspond to any address, not necessarily `0`. E.g. numerically `(char *) 0` can produce a pointer that "points" to address `0xFFFFFFFF`, for one example, if the given platform reserves this address for null-pointer value of `char *` type. But again, from the language point of view, a null-pointer value does not really point anywhere.

`(char *) 9` does not have such special meaning. The pointer that `(char *) 9` produces is also implementation-dependent. In most implementations it will indeed produce a `char *` pointer to address `9`.

In order to work around that special treatment of `(char *) 0` you can try something like

```
int i = 0;
(char *) i;
```

The above `(char *) i` (albeit implementation-dependent too) will usually produce a `char *` pointer to address `0`. The key moment here that disables the special treatment is the fact that `0` in the expression is no longer a constant.