# execv: What is (char *)0 in C?

Tags: c

For example, if I have

```c
/* <…> */
int main(void)
{
  int status;
  pid_t pid;
  char* arg[] = {"ls", "-l", "/usr/include", (char *)0};
  if ((pid=fork()) == 0)
  {
    /* CODICE ESEGUITO DAL FIGLIO - CODE EXECUTED BY THE SON */
    execv("/bin/ls", arg);
    /* Si torna solo in caso di errore - Returns only in case of error */
    exit(/* <…> */
```

Why in the line defining `char* arg[]` there is an element `(char *)0`? What is it?

Comment: How about taking a look at [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6072931/what-does-char-0-mean-in-c)?

Comment: You may have a look at this [set](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[c]+%22%28char*%29+0%22) of questions. Also try searching SO using advanced options before posting questions. I am sure it will be helpful for you :D

Comment: not sure whether or not this should be dupe: the `exec` family of functions has slightly different requirements to `fgets`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's `NULL` pointer. It serves the same purpose in the array as null terminator character `'\0'` serves in C strings - provides a way to determine the last valid position in a collection without passing its length explicitly.

Essentially, `execv` needs to know how many parameters you want to pass. C does not provide a way to find the length of an array passed to a function, so two common patterns are passing the length in a separate parameter and using a marker element to terminate the sequence. For arrays of pointers, `NULL` is a natural marker element.

Another common way to write the same expression is

```
char* arg[]= {"ls", "-l", "/usr/include", NULL};
```

Comment: Oh! Thanks man! ^^

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of this is so that the `execv` function knows when to stop reading arguments.

After all, by passing `arg` you only pass a pointer to the first argument.  The `execv` function will find all the arguments by incrementing this to find the next argument, until it finds a special sentinel value.  According to the documentation of `execv`:

> The array of pointers must be terminated by a NULL pointer.

`(char *)0` is a null pointer of course.
So why did the person write `(char *)0` instead of `NULL`?

They may have mixed up `execv` with `execl` which *does* require that specifically `(char *)0` or equivalently `(char *)NULL` be  passed.

This is because `execl` reads arguments via the varargs mechanism , so the actual argument must be specifically a `char *`.  Passing `NULL` risks that `NULL` is a macro defined to the constant `0` of type `int`, which would break the varargs mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

(char *)0 is equivalent to `NULL` pointer

Comment: C does not define a null pointer constant as a pointer to the address 0.

Comment: @2501 No, but (char *)0 is equivalent to write NULL in that context

Comment: That is true, but that is also not the topic comment, which you didn't address.

Comment: @2501 please explain better.

Comment: Your answer is plain wrong. `0` when used in pointer context is a _null pointer constant_. That is not necessarily identical to address `0x0`. And a _null pointer_ points **nowhere** - that's exactly what it is for. Also `NULL` is a macro, not a pointer. And no, it is not equivalent. See the standard.